# What is the list::insert behavior when the informed iterator argument is initialized to the begining of an empty list?

Tags: c++, list, stl

Suppose you have a C++ empty list:

```
list<int> l;
```

and you insert three new elements from the beginning:

```
auto it = l.begin();
    l.insert(it,10);
    l.insert(it,20);
    l.insert(it,30);
```

when trying to print the list elements from the beginning to the end:

```
for(int i: l){
        cout << i << ' ';
}
```

the obtained result is: `10 20 30`.

But it is supposed that  `insert` function inserts elements **before** the element pointed by the iterator, so the obtained result should have been: `30 20 10`.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3):

When the list is empty, the `begin()` iterator compares equal to the `end()` iterator.  Calling `insert()` with the `end()` iterator inserts the value at the end of the list.  `insert()` does not invalidate any iterators, so your `it` variable is still holding the `end()` iterator each time you are calling `insert()`.

If you want your values to be in the reverse order that you call `insert()`, use the iterator that `insert()` returns to you, eg:

```cpp
auto it = l.begin();
it = l.insert(it,10);
it = l.insert(it,20);
it = l.insert(it,30);
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/FrPi8k)