# How do I sort rest of the elements that I insert in a list by keeping the first insertion remain in its position?

Tags: c++, list, sorting

Suppose I'm trying to insert random stuff on a list in CPP using include list,

```
list <string> newList;
list<string>::iterator z = newList.begin();
//James(Remains static, rest sorted)  -> Abraham-> Brian-> Chuck-> David-> Rick-> Morty
newList.insert(z,James);
newList.insert(z,David);
newList.insert(z, Rick);
newList.insert(z, Abraham);
newList.insert(z, Brian);
newList.insert(z, Morty);
newList.insert(z, Chuck);
```

how, and where do I call the newList.sort() to make all of them sorted except the first insertion, ie James?

Comment: There are good answers provided if you have only 1 James. What do you want to happen if there are multiple James?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a potential solution, by first removing the first entry, then sorting.

```
auto front = newList.front();
newList.pop_front();
newList.sort();
newList.push_front(front);
```

This will make the entire list sorted, but whatever was at the beginning (`James` in your example) will be re-added to the front of the list.

Comment: It says front does not name a type while compiling, what's the probable issue?

Comment: Our solutions are quite similar: Your advantage is that there is tiny bit less sorting needed. My advantage is that iterator to the first element remains valid, and also the type doesn't need to be copiable.

Comment: @nxd Upgrade your compiler.

Comment: @nxd Sounds like your compiler is in legacy C++03 mode (or is old enough that it _only_ supports C++03). The `auto` keyword (in this context) is C++11. But you can solve this very easily by writing `std::string front = newList.front();` And, in fact, I'd recommend that anyway, for clearer code. Types are your friend.

Comment: At least `std::move` the string. You have two copies here. Very wasteful.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution to keep the position of the first element:

- Store iterator to first element
- Sort the list
- Splice the element from the stored iterator back to beginning

If the "first insrertion" is not the first element - elements can be inserted in arbitrary positions after all - then a more complex logic is needed.

Unfotunately, there appears to not exist a general sorting algorithm for sublists in the standard library.

Comment: It's unfortunate that `std::list::sort` can't accept positions, and `std::list` doesn't work with `std::sort`, otherwise, you could specify sub-lists using iterator positions.

Comment: This is the "correct" solution, both in terms of performance and in terms of semantics. You want to be splicing the nodes, not copying values needlessly and messily.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings With move, Chris' solution would be mostly fine, except for the invalidation of the iterator. The stability of the iterators is almost the only reason to ever use a linked list.

Comment: Speaking of iterators, I've just taken another look at the OP's `insert`s, and are we sure `James` is the first element?

Comment: I suppose what was originally `begin()` is the end iterator which remains the end iterator so the `insert`s are push_backs. Or does it remain the begin iterator? Ugh.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Oh. Good point. The comment in code does seem to indicate that they want to keep the first element.

Comment: But it also specifically says that element is `James`. I'm just not entirely convinced that it is. I mean, I'll trust that, but it's fragile/unclear code :(

Comment: It inserts the elements [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925270/what-is-the-listinsert-behavior-when-the-informed-iterator-argument-is-initial). Still unclear code perhaps :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I think that begin of empty must also be the end, and therefore it should to remain as the end iterator because no iterators are invalidated. But it does seem confusing written like that. Edit: Apparently same conclusion in the answer linked by cigien.

Comment: @eerorika But the begin of empty is also the begin, and therefore it should remain as the begin iterator because no iterators are invalidated ;)

Comment: But begin changes after insertion. If the iterator pointed to the new begin, that would mean the iterator is invalidated. The only way *not* to invalidate it is to keep pointing at end.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings But end is more important than begin :) Empty list seems to be an unfortunate special case.

Comment: I remember thinking this is worth a separate question, when I read the question I just linked to :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom comparator, that places `James` before all others:

```
bool compare(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
    if (a == b) return false;
    else if (a == James) return true;
    else if (b == James) return false;
    else return a < b;
}
```

You need to take care of the `a==b` case to have a strict weak ordering (`James < James` must return `false`). Then `James` comes before all others, all other come after `James` and otherwise you simply compare the two elements.

Note that if there is more than one `James` in the list they will both placed in front by this comparsion, so it isn't exactly doing what you asked for.

Comment: What if `James` appears more than once ;)

Comment: @ChrisMM then both will be placed in front :(

Comment: That's good for `James`, which in this case happens to be the first insertion.  But not so good when `Bobby_Tables` is the first insertion.

Comment: @Eljay in the general case I'd use a lambda

Comment: appreciate feedback always, but anyhow it doesnt answer the question, not deleting it because it may be of some use in some special case, but not really motivated to "fix" it any further

Comment: I'd write this as `return std::tie(a == James, a) < std::tie(b == James, b);`

Comment: @Caleth Are you sure that is correct? I'd expect `false` to order before `true`.

Comment: Oops, `!=` instead